# window.opener null after redirect?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, twitter, oauth

So I'm adding a "sign in with Twitter" button onto my web site.  I display the twitter sign in in a popup window.  When the user signs into to twitter they are redirected back to a page on my site which calls a javascript function on the window.opener to notify the page that sign in has completed and to refresh.

The problem is after twitter redirects the user back to my site window.opener is null.  The script works fine if I bypass the twitter sign in page.  Also this appears to be a IE issue, as it works fine in firefox.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When is window.opener null. When you redirect the popup or the parent page? If the latter, that is normal behaviour IIRC,  `opener` points at the opening document not the window.

Comment: Well it points at the `window` object, but yes, `opener` is transient, not surviving a document load. Sign-in in a pop-up window isn't a good idea.

Comment: Yes, to be clear it is the popup that is being redirected and trying to call window.opener.

My requirements are to use the twitter sign in and to not direct a user away from our page.  Twitter blocks using thier login in a iFrame so a popup is my only real option here.

If I can't reference window.opener after redirect then how can I notify the parent window that the child window is closing and login is complete?

Comment: If you really must, cross-window communication is possible using HTML5 `postMessage` on browsers that support it, or failing that writing to `document.cookie` from one window and reading it in another. But this isn't a good idea. “not redirecting a user away from our page” is a classic bogus manager requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect

Answer (score 1):

check [window.opener is null after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect). If you provide a page of your own domain in the popup first it doesnt loose is parent information. At least that how it works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could use a lightbox containing an iframe for the Twitter sign-in.  Then you can use "top" instead of "window.opener".

Comment: That was my first idea.  However twitter has code embedded in thier log in page designed to break the page if displayed in an iFrame.