# Cannot call method 'wsl_wordpress_social_login'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi I'm using a wordpress plugin to allow user to comment using facebook and twitter accounts.

This is the page i am testing the plugin on http://blog.pcpal.co.uk/2012/04/first-raspberry-pi-computers-to-be-delivered/

When i click the facebook icon its opens up a windows where i sign into facebook ad then directs to a blank pages which has a JS error see code below

```
<html><head>
<script>
function init() {
    window.opener.wsl_wordpress_social_login({
        'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
        'provider' : 'Facebook'
    });

    window.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
</body></html>

# Error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'wsl_wordpress_social_login' of null
```

If you can help then great..

Additional info
Only seems to do it with chrome

Comment: I've update this with a link where comments are open... so you can test  The urls are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons the "window.opener" object is likely removed when you go to another domain (like Facebook).  When it gets back to your site it's trying to tell the parent window (the blog) to refresh but it no longer has a way to communicate with it.

The plug-in should add some code to the parent page to watch for the pop-up window to close and then refresh itself.

See [window.opener is null after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect)

Comment: Thanks for this.. it makes sense what you are saying i'll have a look later and confirm your answers