# Javascript event dispached in a popup window that has been redirected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup, dom-events, custom-events

I have a page A that opens a popup to B. Page B, after some jobs, always redirects to another page C in the pop up.
Page C then dispatches an event to send some data to page A, but page A has no reference to page C to register the event handler.
The code I tried is somewhat like this:

PageA:

```
function handler(e) {
    alert(e.detail.message);
}
var popup = window.open('/PageB.aspx');
popup.addEventListener("dispatch", handler, false);
```

PageB:

```
location.href = "PageC.aspx";
```

PageC:

```
var event = new CustomEvent(
        "dispatch",
        {
            detail: {
                message: "Test"
            },
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        }
    );

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

But this is not working, because when I redirect, PageA misses the reference to PageC.
Does anyone knows a way to fix this?

Comment: Is Page C in the same domain as Page A?  If not, you need to use postMessage instead.

Answer (score 1):

If Page C is in the same domain as page A, try

```
window.opener.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If not, you need to use postMessage instead, which means you have to serialize your event to a string and listen for messages on Page A.

Comment: Page C is in the same domain, but in the stuff done by Page B there is also a redirect to another domain that turn to Page C, so the reference to opener is lost. I think that I must use postMessage, but Page A still not have a refecerence to Page C so, can you show me how to do this?

Comment: postMessage won't work unless you have a reference to the parent window.  Try window.parent instead.

Comment: This [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect) might help.