# JavaScript: Get access to parent window from popup | Oauth API

Tags: javascript, google-api

I have some trouble with Google Auth, extended from this [tutorial](http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/):

Exist main window, for Example `win1`

This window contain function

```
$('#gmail-connect').click(function () {
popupWindow = window.open(
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=527884649784.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://25labs.com/demo/import-gmail-contacts/oauth.php&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code','', 'width=900,height=600,resizable,scrollbars');
});
```

In this popup ('win2') Google redirects me to defined callback URL that contains code:

```
<html>
    <script>
        {literal}
            function makeResponse() {
                if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
                    window.opener.foo();
                }
                return;
                window.close();
            }
        {/literal}
    </script>
    <body onload="makeResponse();"></body>
</html>
```

So the problem is that I cant get window.opener access to parent window, caused redirect. How to fix it?

Comment: window.opener is removed whenever you navigate to a different host see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7120534

Comment: @RodrigoAssis: Consider posting the comment as an answer