# Unable to refresh the parent page after closing the popup in javascript in IE 11

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

On an aspx page, there is a link that opens as a popup to authorize users to login to twitter or facebook. I am doing this using tweetsharp and facebook sdk api.

After authorizing the user, I am trying to close the popup and refresh the parent page using javascript. This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.parent.opener.location.reload(true);
    }        
</script>
```

This is not working in IE 11. Can you suggest a solution for this please? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Still unable to fix this issue.

I tried to use the above code for non-IE browsers, and for IE browsers I tried to use window.showModalDialog() to open the modaldialog instead of popup and that way, it will freeze the parent window until the modal window is closed. Then I tried to refresh the window. Here is the code:

```
function myfunction() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {// If Internet Explorer, return version number
        OpenModalPopUP();
    }
    else                 // If another browser, return 0
    {
        newwindow = window.open('/Login.aspx', window, 'height=500,width=450');
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
    }


    return false;
}

function OpenModalPopUP() {
    window.showModalDialog('/Login.aspx');
    window.location.reload(); //this will only reload the page after modal dialog is closed.
}
```

But even this is not working, when I submit the login form, it is opening the result in a new window.

Comment: Try document.parent.reload();

Comment: thanks, that didnt work either.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Try this it worked for me
window.opener.document.location.href = 'Default.aspx'; --> (give ur parent window url here)

window.close();

Comment: thanks, but the window.close is also not working when I add this..

Comment: Actually, login.aspx redirects to settings.aspx after logging in and the js code is in settings.aspx. Do you think, because the page has been redirected, this code is not working? the refresh js code is in settings.aspx

Comment: Can you paste the js code in the parent window rather than in the child window and try the above logic

Comment: you mean use this code in parent? window.opener.document.location.href = 'Default.aspx'; --> (give ur parent window url here) window.close();

this will close the parent window, right?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue is. It is happenining only in IE though.

[window.opener is null after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120534/window-opener-is-null-after-redirect)