# window.opener is null, parent window cannot access its own popup, or JavaScript runtime error 0x800706b5 (facebook, twitter login or paypal payments)

Tags: javascript, oauth, window.open, window.opener

After sinking a lot of time into this issue, I want to make the solution searchable for anyone else who encounters the same problem.

**Common use scenario**

- You want to implement external authentication with a provider such as Twitter, Facebook, Microsoft, GitHub, or any other site that supports OAuth; or
- You want to implement external payment with a provider such as Braintree, Paypal, etc.
- You are already using a server-side OAuth library, for example Owin with NuGet package(s) to support Twitter and Facebook, as in ASP.net projects generated with the New Project wizard. You might also be using another library, or developing in another MVC ecosystem like Ruby or Node.js/React.
- You want to open a window to perform authentication and close that window when it succeeds or fails, instead of redirecting the user out of your site temporarily. Since your site is a Single Page Application, redirecting the entire view ruins the user experience.
- You are testing all this from localhost, by having your run action open localhost:port. Also, you are using IE or Edge as the browser.

**Symptoms**

You wire up "Login with XXX" button to execute JavaScript that opens a new window with a GET request to your external login controller which then sends a 302 redirect to external login provider's OAuth endpoint with OAuth information attached ("challenge" step).

At this point, attempting to access the popup window from the parent window will throw JS error 0x800706b5 (object has been disposed or no longer available). This is OK, because the window no longer belongs to us, until it redirects back to our site. We handle this edge case with try/catch and eat exceptions until it becomes available again.

User authorizes your app (a POST to external provider) and provider redirects back to your site. Alternatively, provider detected that user is already signed in & approved the app so it redirects back to your site. In either case. popup is back in your zone, with a GET processed by one of your controllers.

**Problem**

The page from your site that's inside the popup cannot access it's opener because it's now null. If you attempted a work-around by instead having its parent store a reference and keep checking that reference inside of a try block, the reference does NOT become valid after the popup URI is back to your domain. If you uploaded your site to the server, this would work and the reference would become valid, allowing parent to check a window variable set by the child (such as requestingClose) and call close() to close the child.

Answer (score 2):

The solution has been provided by Alex Altotsky in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30698397/3727395):

Here are the explicit steps required to make your site running on localhost in IE/Edge be able to access its popups after they redirect back:

- Go to Internet Options > Security
- Select Trusted Sites icon (zone)
- Change Security Level to exactly the same setting as the Security level for Internet zone (Medium-high by default).
- Ensure Enable Protected Mode is likewise identical to Internet zone (checked by default).
- Click Sites
- Add http://localhost
- Uncheck Require server verification
- Close the Sites dialog
- Click Apply on Internet Options dialog

Comment: For posterity as well as keeping track of what I learned, see my project here which adds Twitter and Facebook popup logins to ASP.NET app starting from a standard template: https://github.com/valeriy-novytskyy/login/